# What is the belief parameter (nu)?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, glmm

I am reading up on MCMCglmm in R using [this course](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf) - could someone explain to me what the belief parameter is, it is first mentioned on page 12. I would like to understand it, and it's relationship to the Wishart distribution and parameter V.

> For a single variance component the inverse Wishart takes two scalar
>   parameters, V and nu. The distribution tends to a point mass on V as
>   the degree of belief parameter, nu goes to innity. The distribution
>   tends to be right skewed when nu is not very large, with a mode of
>   Vnu nu+2 but a mean of Vnu nu2 (which is not dened for nu < 2).1

*Reading material suggestions in the comments would also be really helpful as I look for beginner material in Bayesian Statistics as a newbie/non-mathematician - I'm an evolutionary biologist :)*

Comment: The package by Hadfield you reference does seem to 'jump right in' if you're new to Bayesian approaches. After looking around a good deal I found [Kruschke's](http://www.amazon.com/Doing-Bayesian-Data-Analysis-Tutorial/dp/0123814855) book to be the best introduction; as far as GLMModels, there's a good example with logistic regression which you should be able to generalize. As a beginner, I also liked [Gelmans](http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Regression-Multilevel-Hierarchical-Models/dp/052168689X) book. Both are intended for those coming from non-math backgrounds.

Comment: @dardisco I found a great intro set of lessons on Udacity - https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-st101/l-48703346/m-48369847